# Prove that the norm of the rejection of vector a on vector b is equal to the norm of the cross product between a and normalized b

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors

I am a Cegep student and I just finished learning basic linear algebras at school. I started learning computer graphics, and there is this one formula that really confuses me, so I tried to derive the formula. However, I got a different formula, and after comparing the differences, I found something pretty interesting, but I cannot prove it.

Can anyone prove the following equation? (Sorry, I do not know how to format math equation in stack exchange)

Let's say there exist a vector ***a*** and ***b***

Prove that the norm of the rejection of vector ***a*** on vector ***b*** is equal to the norm of the cross product between ***a*** and normalized ***b***.

If I am wrong in my equation, please correct me.

This is the equation in photo
[image]

Thank you very much!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is a visual representation of a rejection. I know many people do not use this term.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRPBr.png)

Comment: Note:  the term you want is "projection", not "rejection".

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction. But I believe that it is rejection and not projection. Rejection of a on b is the same as the orthogonal vector of b that starts from the head of a, and ends when it intersects with b

Comment: Hint: the norm of the cross product of two vectors is the area of the parallelogram determined by them, given by "base times height". If the base is a unit vector, what is that area equal to?

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. I understand now. Since the base is 1 therefore the whole  norm of the cross product is also the height of the parallelogram. And the height is indeed the rejection of vector a on b!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• By usual trigonometry you have $\Vert\vec r\Vert=\Vert\vec a\Vert\sin\alpha$ in the following picture.
[image: projection and rejection]
On the other hand one basic property for the cross product is
$\bbox[4px,border:2px]{
\Vert\vec u \times\vec v\Vert
=\Vert\vec u\Vert\mathbin.\Vert\vec v\Vert
\mathbin.\vert\sin(\vec u\mathbin; \vec v)\vert.
}$

We then have $\left\Vert\vec b\right\Vert\mathbin.\Vert\vec r\Vert
=\left\Vert\vec b\right\Vert\mathbin.\Vert\vec a\Vert
\mathbin\sin\alpha
=\left\Vert\vec a\times\vec b\right\Vert$ and your result follows:
$$\Vert\vec r\Vert
=\frac{\left\Vert\vec a\times\vec b\right\Vert}
{\big\Vert\vec b\big\Vert}
=\left\Vert \vec a\times
\frac{\vec b}{\big\Vert\vec b\big\Vert} \right\Vert
\cdot$$

• Another possible proof relies on [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) for the cross product:
$\bbox[4px,border:2px]{
\vec u\times\big(\vec v\times\vec w\big)
=(\vec u\mathbin.\vec w)\vec v-\big(\vec u\mathbin.v\big)\vec w
}$ (where $\vec x\mathbin.\vec y$ stands for the scalar product of two vectors).

In our case it gives $\vec b\times\big(\vec a\times\vec b\big)
=\vec b\times\big(\vec r\times\vec b\big)
=\left\Vert\vec b\right\Vert^2\vec r$,
thus $\Vert\vec r\Vert
=\frac{\left\Vert\vec b\times(\vec a\times\vec b)\right\Vert}{\big\Vert\vec b\big\Vert^2}
=\frac{\Vert\vec b\Vert\mathbin.\left\Vert\vec a\times\vec b\right\Vert}{\big\Vert\vec b\big\Vert^2}$, etc.